# Moved from windows lost all my files - Any File recovery Tools

Tags: data-recovery, undelete

Previously i was using the windows 7. When i try to replace the windows to ubuntu i lost all of my other drive files. Is there any way to recover these files. I have my project files and some important files in one of my folder. Anyone pls help...

Ok Is there any chance to recover a single file. I have photorec and testdisk and dono how to use them. I do now need "presentation.ppt" file is this possible.

Comment: What do you mean you lost all your files? Do you still have windows installed but cannot boot to it? Have you completely removed windows? Do your windows partitions appear in your ubuntu session?

Comment: I lost all my drives. 3 drives become single drive.Windows was completely removed.Any idea?

Comment: Sorry but ... you seriously did not think to back up that file when you started messing with your operating system? Not even think to copy it over to an USB stick before you stared?

Answer (score 4):

There is still hopes of getting some documents out from you old Windows Partition using an Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB. From there you can use testdisk to get files from previous partitions. There is no guarantee, but i'm almost sure if you have not filled out your Ubuntu partition you will be able to get many files back:

Look at the guide [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)

Comment: Wow, I really didn't think that was possible sorry. When it says 'replace' Windows (and lose all your files) I thought it meant what it said. Surely when you make a new partition table with just Ubuntu in it, it is fixed and you lose your files? Or is Ubuntu not being very efficient and leaving Windows space?

Comment: I guess you should dig more into partitioning then. Creating a new partition table does definitely not wipe the drive. The disk space that is use for Ubuntu i of course wiped, but the rest of the files are actually there until you write new data. The operating system just does not see them because of the new partition table. All this is of course only if you did not rewrite your whole disk with zeros :)

Comment: I see, so, basically, the OS lies. Fair enough :D